# Spring Autowire not work for GenericApplicationContext

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, autowired

I got some problems when trying to build an GenericApplicationContext, all the fields annotated with @Autowired are null. Following is the code for building application context:

```
GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext(
            new DefaultListableBeanFactory());
XmlBeanDefinitionReader lXmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(
            context);
lXmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new FileSystemResource(      "/applicationContext.xml"));
```

I'm sure the annotation-config and component scan things are proper configured in applicationContext.xml, so do I need some more processing to explicitly wire dependency? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Show us your XML, your bean and most importantly - how you obtain an instance of that bean. Also - your whole code above can be replaced by a single line, I don't think you need all this boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think I've found the reason. It's nothing about the XML, just need one more step, to invoke context.refresh() method, all the auto wire stuff will be handled inside this method. For general purpose, you're right, I can load the context by just a single line, but it's just because I'm trying to integrate my project into an open source framework of WebSocket server, which use GenericApplicationContext to separate contexts by namespace for various plugin, actually the above code is what they provide, so I need to fix it to run it up. Anyway, it works now, thanks.